# English NER Annotator for Stanford CoreNLP v 4.0.0 missing some entity types compared to v 3.9.2

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I recently upgrade to Stanford CoreNLP v 4.0.0 from v 3.9.2 and noticing that it seems to have reduced performance in regards to NER. In particular, v4 seems to not recognize as many entities and not recognizing URLs, or EMAILs at all. Version 4 also doesn't recognize Google as an ORGANIZATION anymore (still recognizes Microsoft but I havent done many tests on other organizations yet). I was wondering if there is a change in how v4 should be used? The documentation doesn't seem to indicate any differences in usage from what I can see.

The change log at https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/history.html doesn't seem to imply that NER in English should be affected (although it does state that there is a new UDv2 tokenization that affects tagging and parsing). I did notice that the jar files between v4 and v3.9.2 are different with v4 being significantly smaller.

To demonstrate the differences, consider for example the basic following input datafile that includes all entity types and has the following text on each line (i.e. two files `basic.txt` and `basic4.txt` are identical and contain the string elements on each line listed below).

```
he 
cancer.
Los Angeles
California
Google
two days
Convention
night actor
special interest
todays ego
$1 million
100%
tonight, not sure
10/10
Islam
Nicole.
Europe
https://www.tom.com
fans@tom.com
@therealdeal
USA
```

Running the following two commands (where the environment variables `$CORENLP` and `$CORENLP4` point to the directory containing versions 3.9.2 and 4.0.0 respectively, each of which has the english models jar file relevant for each version). The output for the two versions is computed with the two commands

```
 java -mx2g -cp "$CORENLP4/*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -ssplit.eolonly true -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -file basic4.txt -outputFormat text

 java -mx2g -cp "$CORENLP/*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -ssplit.eolonly true -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner -file basic.txt -outputFormat text
```

Giving two output files. `basic4.txt.out` and `basic.txt.out` respectively. The newer 4.0.0 version of CORENLP doesnt seem to be able to identify URL, emails and also doesnt recognize Google as an Organization.

To succinctly demonstrate, the output of the diff command is given below. It shows that the different versions identify most of the entities (with extra details in v4). However, v4 misses the URL, EMAIL and Google as an ORGANIZATION as mentioned earlier.

```
diff basic.txt.out basic4.txt.out > corenlp.diff

1c1
< Document: ID=basic.txt (21 sentences, 34 tokens)
---
> Document: ID=basic4.txt (21 sentences, 34 tokens)
10c10
< he    PERSON
---
> he    PERSON  -
20c20
< cancer    CAUSE_OF_DEATH
---
> cancer    CAUSE_OF_DEATH  -
30c30
< Los Angeles   CITY
---
> Los Angeles   CITY    LOCATION:0.9501291593275937
39c39
< California    STATE_OR_PROVINCE
---
> California    STATE_OR_PROVINCE   LOCATION:0.558758796557467
45c45
< [Text=Google CharacterOffsetBegin=35 CharacterOffsetEnd=41 PartOfSpeech=NNP Lemma=Google NamedEntityTag=ORGANIZATION]
---
> [Text=Google CharacterOffsetBegin=35 CharacterOffsetEnd=41 PartOfSpeech=NNP Lemma=Google NamedEntityTag=O]
48d47
< Google    ORGANIZATION
58c57
< two days  DURATION
---
> two days  DURATION    DURATION:-1.0
64c63
< [Text=Convention CharacterOffsetBegin=51 CharacterOffsetEnd=61 PartOfSpeech=NNP Lemma=Convention NamedEntityTag=O]
---
> [Text=Convention CharacterOffsetBegin=51 CharacterOffsetEnd=61 PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=convention NamedEntityTag=O]
76,77c75,76
< night TIME
< actor TITLE
---
> night TIME    TIME:-1.0
> actor TITLE   -
87c86
< special interest  IDEOLOGY
---
> special interest  IDEOLOGY    -
97c96
< todays    SET
---
> todays    SET SET:-1.0
108c107
< $1 million    MONEY
---
> $1 million    MONEY   MONEY:0.999511595823616
118c117
< 100%  PERCENT
---
> 100%  PERCENT PERCENT:0.9157902320089298
124c123
< [Text=tonight CharacterOffsetBegin=118 CharacterOffsetEnd=125 PartOfSpeech=RB Lemma=tonight NamedEntityTag=DATE NormalizedNamedEntityTag=THIS NI Timex=<TIMEX3 alt_value="THIS NI" anchorTimeID="t0" temporalFunction="true" tid="t4" type="DATE" valueFromFunction="tf0">tonight</TIMEX3>]
---
> [Text=tonight CharacterOffsetBegin=118 CharacterOffsetEnd=125 PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=tonight NamedEntityTag=DATE NormalizedNamedEntityTag=THIS NI Timex=<TIMEX3 alt_value="THIS NI" anchorTimeID="t0" temporalFunction="true" tid="t4" type="DATE" valueFromFunction="tf0">tonight</TIMEX3>]
130c129
< tonight   DATE
---
> tonight   DATE    DATE:-1.0
139c138
< 10/10 NUMBER
---
> 10/10 NUMBER  NUMBER:-1.0
148c147
< Islam RELIGION
---
> Islam RELIGION    ORGANIZATION:0.4330241395436507
158c157
< Nicole    PERSON
---
> Nicole    PERSON  PERSON:0.8292894556058169
167c166
< Europe    LOCATION
---
> Europe    LOCATION    LOCATION:0.8992206702193217
173c172
< [Text=https://www.tom.com CharacterOffsetBegin=163 CharacterOffsetEnd=182 PartOfSpeech=NNP Lemma=https://www.tom.com NamedEntityTag=URL]
---
> [Text=https://www.tom.com CharacterOffsetBegin=163 CharacterOffsetEnd=182 PartOfSpeech=ADD Lemma=https://www.tom.com NamedEntityTag=O]
176d174
< https://www.tom.com   URL
182c180
< [Text=fans@tom.com CharacterOffsetBegin=183 CharacterOffsetEnd=195 PartOfSpeech=NNP Lemma=fans@tom.com NamedEntityTag=EMAIL]
---
> [Text=fans@tom.com CharacterOffsetBegin=183 CharacterOffsetEnd=195 PartOfSpeech=ADD Lemma=fans@tom.com NamedEntityTag=O]
185d182
< fans@tom.com  EMAIL
191c188
< [Text=@therealdeal CharacterOffsetBegin=196 CharacterOffsetEnd=208 PartOfSpeech=NN Lemma=@therealdeal NamedEntityTag=HANDLE]
---
> [Text=@therealdeal CharacterOffsetBegin=196 CharacterOffsetEnd=208 PartOfSpeech=JJ Lemma=@therealdeal NamedEntityTag=HANDLE]
194c191
< @therealdeal  HANDLE
---
> @therealdeal  HANDLE  -
203c200
< USA   COUNTRY
---
> USA   COUNTRY LOCATION:0.7231044794961725
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, single word sentences aren't handled well by the NER models, since those models use the surrounding context to process the text.  The hard coded expressions for high precision NER don't include google or Google, but you could make that change if you like.  Note that sometimes it can identify Google as an ORG by itself as there is a mechanism for remembering which words it sees in a lowercase or uppercase context first.  If you ask 3.9.2 for "Google" and then "google", it will identify "Google" as an ORG.  If you ask in the reverse order, it will identify neither as ORG.

The issue with not recognizing emails or urls is that the high precision NER is only set to apply to nouns or adjectives, and the new version introduced a new POS tag for addresses.  We can change the code on our end so that in the future this will be detected by default.  In the meantime, you can add this option to your command line and it should once again detect urls and emails:

-ner.fine.regexner.mapping "ignorecase=true,validpospattern=^(NN|JJ|ADD).*,edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/english/gazetteers/regexner_caseless.tab;edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/english/gazetteers/regexner_cased.tab"